# XMLHttpRequest, SHA512 and BTC - E

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, sha512

I am making an XMLHttpRequest to BTC - E. API documentation can be seen here: https://btc-e.com/api/documentation

```
var apiKey;
var apiSec;
var response;
var nonce;
var sign;

function signMessage() {
    nonce = (new Date()).getTime().toString();
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512("?method=getInfo&nonce=" + nonce, apiSec);
    sign = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
}

function getPrice() {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST","https://btc-e.com/tapi", false);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Key", apiKey);
req.setRequestHeader("Sign", sign);
req.send("method=getInfo&nonce=" + nonce);
req.onload = function() {
    response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
};
}
signMessage();
getPrice();
console.log(responce);
```

It seems that the hashing is done correctly or at least getting a correct looking string back. Server response: {"success":0,"error":"invalid nonce parameter; on key:0, you sent:1389814528941"}

Have struggled for hours and can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Does that api support CORS? What does your network inspector say about the requests, do they look as you expect? Why is your POST data preceded by a question mark?

Comment: I have done it in a similar fashion using another site (Bitstamp) and everything worked perfectly. Question mark is because "Sign — POST data (?param=val&param1=val1) signed by a secret key according to HMAC-SHA512 method;"

Answer (score 1):

Btc-e is capped at 4294967294 for nonces. https://www.npmjs.org/package/btc-e